# jQuery 1.4.4: How to find an element based on its data-attribute value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle, custom-data-attribute

I imagine this should be a pretty trivial task but using Firefox for Mac, 3.6.12 the following does not work:

```
// assign data attributes
$('.gallery li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('slide',i+1);
});

// outputting an empty jQuery object
console.log($('.gallery li[data-slide]'));

// this does not work either outputting an empty jQuery object
console.log($("[data-slide]"));
```

using Firebug I can see that all the data-slide attributes including their numerical value are correctly attached to the `li`s and logging out:

```
$('.gallery li').each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).data());
});
```

outputs as expected:

```
Object { slide=1}
Object { slide=2}
Object { slide=3}
Object { slide=4}
```

So why does the first `console.log` not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`data` adds items to jQuery's internal data holder, not to the `data-` attributes.  These are read **into** jQuery's `data()` structure, but values inserted using jQuery are not fed back into the DOM.

The easiest way to mimic this would be using `.filter()`:

```
// To replicate $('.gallery li[data-slide]')
$('.gallery li').filter(function(){
    return (undefined !== $(this).data('slide'));
});
```

---

You could also do this as a custom selector:

```
$.expr[':'].hasData = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
    return (undefined !== $(obj).data(meta[3]));
};

$('.gallery li:hasData(slide)'); // li elements under .gallery with "slide" data set
$(':hasData(slide)'); // any element with "slide" data set
```

Comment: ah okay, i had misunderstood the `.data()` function as a shortcut for the data-attribute in html5. So to read/write to those i will need to do `$(el).attr('data-slide',1)`?

Comment: @Jannis - if you aren't actually interested in `data()` and just want  attributes, use `.attr()`

Comment: @Jannis If you really want to. Why not use `.data()`, though? Much more flexible and powerful -- e.g. you can set values other than strings. Also note that `data()` won't be updated by using `attr()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Super useful, once I switched things over to using `.attr('data-* …` it all works. What I still don't quite understand though is how the `.data` method is 'better' seeing as it makes it much harder finding elements based on their current data value? _or am i missing something here…?_

Comment: @Jannis Finding elements is not really what data attributes are for.  They are quite simply for storing data.  In this case, you should probably take the semantic approach and add a `slide` class, or something similar.