# Finding an element that contains a certain data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list like so

```
<ul id="a">
<li data-id="i1" data-pk-type="foo bar">sdfsf</li>
<li data-id="i2" data-pk-type="foo">sdfs</li>
<li data-id="i3" data-pk-type="bar baz">sfdsf</li>
<li data-id="i4" data-pk-type="qux foo">sfds</li>
<li data-id="i5" data-pk-type="baz">sdff</li>
</ul>
```

I want to find all the elements that contain a given `data-pk-type`. I am trying the following unsuccessful code because `.data("pkType", "foo")` actually sets the data attribute to `foo`;

```
var $links = $("#a").find("li").data("pkType", "foo");
```

I could do something like

```
var $links = $("#a").find("li", "[data-pk-type='foo']");
```

however that wouldn't work as well… I want any element that might contain `foo`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Description

You should use jQuerys `Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]`.

> **Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring

Check out the sample and [jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/J6tkZ/6/)

#### Sample

```
$links = $("li[data-pk-type*='foo']");
alert($links.length);
```

will give you a 3, so 3 elements was found.

#### More Information

- [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- [jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/J6tkZ/6/)

Comment: Or you could use build in methods (if you are not using jQuery):
`document.querySelectorAll("[data-pk-type]")` => Array of elements.

Answer (score 6):

Try based on this documentation
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

It will be like

```
var $links = $('li[data-pk-type~="foo"]',$("#a"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I've previously answered a very similar question: [jQuery 1.4.4: How to find an element based on its data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198403/jquery-1-4-4-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-its-data-attribute-value/4198471#4198471). (I fancy you may have seen it already, since I got an upvote on it this afternoon.)

Basically, I think you're using the wrong tool here. `data-` attributes should be used for storing data that doesn't logically fit into the normal attributes. In this case, your `data-id` and `data-pk-type` logically map to the normal `id` attribute and to the normal `class` attribute. This is especially true because you want to find one of a set of space-separated "types" – exactly the same implementation as classes.

Using normal attributes will make your elements much easier and quicker to find.

```
<ul id="a">
<li id="i1" class="pk-foo pk-bar">sdfsf</li>
<li id="i2" class="pk-foo">sdfs</li>
<li id="i3" class="pk-bar pk-baz">sfdsf</li>
<li id="i4" class="pk-qux pk-foo">sfds</li>
<li id="i5" class="pk-baz">sdff</li>
</ul>
```

Note that I have "namespaced" the classes with `pk-`. This may not be necessary depending on how variant and numerous they are.

You can then find the elements with a normal selector:

```
$('li.pk-foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Short:

```
$("#a").find("li[data-pk-type='foo']");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this `$("#a").find("li[data-pk-type='foo']");`

for more info read about jquery selectors from [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)